# Is it falling or felling?

Tags: word-choice

When you are talking about the fall of a place and you want to say

> ... helped with the xxx of said place ...

is it *falling* or *felling*?

Comment: Are you asking about something like "Ill discipline caused the fall of Rome"?

Comment: no i am sadly not (helped with the felling/falling of Diaz)

Comment: An example sentence would help here.

Comment: A 'place' cannot fall unless you are talking about a very large landslide. Institutions, governments, reputations, expectations, profits and civilisations can all be observed to fall. Persons may fall from grace, fall from favour, fall from power and fall into bad habits.

Comment: Neither is correct. '... contributed to the fall of Rome'. As BigBadCat suggests.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I'm sitting here trying to figure out how "Neither is correct" contributed to the fall of Rome. ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Felling* is associated with the idea of (some agent) making the subject fall, while *falling* refers simply to the subject's fall.

> **fell** *verb*
> 1 Cut down (a tree)
> ‘33 million trees are felled each day’
> 1.1 Knock down.
> ‘Whitlock felled him with one punch’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fell)
>
> **fall** *verb*
> 4 (no object, with adverbial) Be captured or defeated.
> ‘their mountain strongholds fell to enemy attack’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fall)

Use *felling* if you're focusing on (or alluding to) the reason or agent for the fall. This figure of speech drawn from the *felling* of trees is an unusual turn of phrase, but it is not entirely unknown in print:

- This independence was the basis of Adam Smith's teaching and flattered the somewhat self-satisfied people of his time. The optimism, however, had to be broken and it was Malthus who did the felling of the image ...
  ([Population Problems of the Age of Malthus](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=NkUoqtdA4oAC&pg=PA91&dq=%22the%20felling%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvjYzd2LXZAhUDWbwKHQq6CY44MhDoAQhJMAY#v=onepage&q=%22the%20felling%20of%22&f=false) by G. Talbot Griffith)
- recall the trumpets of Revelation and the felling of the walls of Jericho by Joshua
  ([The Orchestration of the Arts](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=zFVFBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA200&dq=%22the%20felling%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRudL92bXZAhUDPrwKHficBsE4RhDoAQhfMAk#v=onepage&q=%22the%20felling%20of%22&f=false) edited by M. Kronegger)

The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20felled%20by&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20felled%20by%3B%2Cc0) for the phrase "was felled by" produces many more examples. Refining the search phrase in the [click-through](https://www.google.com.au/search?lr=lang_en&dcr=0&biw=1920&bih=987&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=YAaOWorCNIOJ8wWdzqioAw&q=%22was%20felled%20by%22%20-timber%20-tree&oq=%22was%20felled%20by%22%20-timber%20-tree&gs_l=psy-ab.3...17838.18741.0.18979.6.6.0.0.0.0.216.647.2-3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.l8WtID3LIh0) to the underlying instances to exclude "tree" and "timber" reports many people among those "felled".

For something more prosaic, especially if you're focusing on the fall itself, use *falling*.

Comment: '... felling of Rome' is totally unacceptable. And if you're focusing on the fall itself, stick with 'fall'.

Comment: Pretty much you only "fell" a (reasonably large) tree or something metaphorically similar, such as a person of some social/economic/political stature.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's not completely unheard of in print. I've added a couple of examples.

Comment: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fall+of+Rome%2Cfall+of+Jericho%2Cfall+of+Troy%2Cfelling+of+Rome%2Cfelling+of+Jericho%2Cfelling+of+Troy%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfall%20of%20Rome%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfall%20of%20Jericho%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfall%20of%20Troy%3B%2Cc0). "Ngrams not found: felling of Rome, felling of Jericho, felling of Troy " '... felling of Rome' is 99.99% unacceptable.

Comment: @Edwin Please refer to the second bullet point in my answer for a reference to Jericho. The point isn't that Rome or Jericho was *felled*. It is that to reference the one who 'made' it fall, one option is to say that it was 'felled' (by said person). Simply saying that it had fallen makes no reference to those who were key to its fall.

Comment: But one reference doesn't bestow acceptability, and the lack of other examples is a far stronger argument against idiomaticity.

Comment: @Edwin I've added further [Ngram](https://www.google.com.au/search?lr=lang_en&dcr=0&biw=1920&bih=987&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=YAaOWorCNIOJ8wWdzqioAw&q=%22was%20felled%20by%22%20-timber%20-tree&oq=%22was%20felled%20by%22%20-timber%20-tree&gs_l=psy-ab.3...17838.18741.0.18979.6.6.0.0.0.0.216.647.2-3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.l8WtID3LIh0) support. There are many examples.

Comment: I've given up looking after 40 results, not one of which uses a geographical place as the direct object. Which is what OP is asking about. And notice that your example uses 'the felling of the walls of Jericho'.

Comment: @Edwin I was rebutting the assertion that *felled* could only be used with trees and not figuratively. And yes, my second example does refer to a structure. The second page of the Ngram listing includes the felling of the Titanic. Adding "Rome" to the search has "... like Gibbon's dictum that Rome was felled by the rise of Christian superstition" ([link](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=-HtOGVIFc0EC&q=%22Rome+was+felled+by%22+-timber+-tree&dq=%22Rome+was+felled+by%22+-timber+-tree&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw0sXiq7jZAhWFW5QKHR2LCBcQ6AEIKTAA)).

Comment: @Edwin Civilisations tend to *decline* rather than be *felled*. For individual cities, violence tends to be more graphically illustrated by *sacked*. *Felled* has an element of intrigue that is harder to prove. Perhaps that accounts for its rarity with respect to geographical places. But since *people* can be said to be felled, it's not out of the question for *places* to be as well. I've provided a couple of *place* examples now, as well as a link to many *people* examples. I think I've made my case, which is that *felling* references someone behind the fall, which *fall* on its own doesn't.

Comment: But that's not the precise usage (the felling of Rome) and is one antiquated example. You can't seriously maintain that OP should use 'this helped with the falling / felling of [Rome]' rather than 'this contributed to the fall / defeat of Rome'.

Comment: @Edwin Suppose *AnEmpire* fell due to a failure to govern effectively (*Reason*), and that failure was attributed to the politicians' unhealthy appetite for leisure (*ContributingCause*). Then I *am* seriously maintaining that one could say "*AnEmpire* was **felled** by *Reason*", or in the OP's formulation, that "*ContributingCause* helped with the felling of AnEmpire". I wouldn't go so far as to say that your "contributed to" phrasing is unidiomatic, but I prefer the phrasing "helped with the *felling* of" to "helped with the *falling* of" (which, incidentally, differs from your phrasing).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth By the way, your “contributed to the fall of Rome” phrasing is idiomatic. But since you referenced “precise usage” (presumably the OP’s), are you willing to argue that their “helped with the [falling] of said place” phrasing is as well?

Comment: 'Idiomatic' has the default meaning 'in common use [by proficient writers / speakers]', not 'relating to set phrases known as idioms', as has been discussed on ELU before. But there seems to be not even a single example for 'helped with the falling of [Rome / Troy ...]', so I've got to say that it's not in the least idiomatic. And the odd archaic / idiosyncratic usage of 'helped with the felling of an Empire' doesn't make that idiomatic either.